# How to automatically select the first entry of the wildmenu without having to tab?

Tags: vimrc, command-line, wildmenu

In vim's command-line, after typing the first few characters, when I press the `tab` key, the wildmenu appears. However, irritatingly, it requires me one additional press of the `tab` key to select the first entry.

Most of the time, it is the first entry I am looking for anyway.

How can I configure vim to automatically select the first entry whenever the wildmenu is activated?

Note: I just want to select the first entry, i.e. highlight it and ready to be activated. I still wish to retain the standard behaviour of manually activating the selection with `<CR>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to set `wildmode` accordingly to your needs, [`:h 'wildmode'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wildmode%27):

> ```
> Completion mode that is used for the character specified with
> 'wildchar'.  It is a comma separated list of up to four parts.  Each
> part specifies what to do for each consecutive use of 'wildchar'.  The
> first part specifies the behavior for the first use of 'wildchar',
> The second part for the second use, etc.
> These are the possible values for each part:
>
> ""                Complete only the first match.
>
> "full"            Complete the next full match.  After the last match,
>                   the original string is used and then the first match
>                   again.
>
> "longest"         Complete till longest common string.  If this doesn't
>                   result in a longer string, use the next part.
>
> "longest:full"    Like "longest", but also start 'wildmenu' if it is
>                   enabled.
>
> "list"            When more than one match, list all matches.
>
> "list:full"       When more than one match, list all matches and
>                   complete first match.
>
> "list:longest"    When more than one match, list all matches and
>                   complete till longest common string.
> ```

For example, I would recommend you:

```
set wildmode=longest,list:full
```

Comment: Wow. Cool. That indeed does work. Thank you for the answer. I have accepted it.